# UI doesn't look great

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I like web design, I have built some web sites. However I think there is a common problem in my UI style. I think my designs don't look good, and are dull looking.

Here is an example site/form I designed and it has that problem. So I would like some advice from a UI designer.

- What is the mistake I have made in this example design?
- Wwhat is some advice you can give me to improve its look?

[image]

Comment: @devin i edited it .is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can see what's going wrong here. You seem to be going for flat and minimalist, but you're missing the underlying core ideas of minimalism.

It's *not* about having **few** things. It's about having **as few as possible**.

You don't need much to look good. But from that flows the idea that what you DO have, MUST be good. There are less things to consider, so you have more time to consider each. So in theory the resulting whole should look much better than something where you spend less time per individual thing.

For example; whitespace. It's essential to minimalism. You're trying to make things look better by adding literally nothing. Just a bunch of nothing. Yet by using it well, you can clump similar things together, you can draw the eye, and you can keep focus on parts. It's an incredibly powerful tool. And one thing that popped out for me right away, is that your  left and right borders have different whitespace. Why?

Then the second big tool of minimalism is placement, and I want to specifically mention alignment. Just like with whitespace, you're not adding anything. You're just moving things around to create order. Aligning things implies a connection, misaligning things implies differences. You've got this right with the question number and answer numbers.

Anyway it's getting late over here so I'll leave you with two mockups that minimize your current layout even further. I hope it's of use, and I'll check back tomorrow to perhaps explain better.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: tnx you so much .yes you a right placement is big problem for me .can you tell me what should i read to know about correct placement?